# What Does It Mean For a C++ Function To Be Inline?

Tags: c++, inline-functions

See title: what does it mean for a C++ function to be inline?

Comment: Maybe someone more experienced with C++ can edit the question to include sample code (ie. `inline diff operator~ (...)`)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The function is placed in the code, rather than being called, similar to using macros (conceptually).

This can improve speed (no function call), but causes code bloat (if the function is used 100 times, you now have 100 copies).

You should note this does not force the compiler to make the function inline, and it will ignore you if it thinks its a bad idea. Similarly the compiler may decide to make normal functions inline for you.

This also allows you to place the entire function in a header file, rather than implementing it in a cpp file (which you can't anyways, since then you get an unresolved external if it was declared inline, unless of course only that cpp file used it).

Comment: Yes, and it's a key point is that modern compilers inline automatically, and using an 'inline' keyword is just a suggestion to the compiler.  Modern compilers generally know what they are doing and correctly choose to inline or not regardless of 'inline' keywords.  But it's still a useful concept.

Comment: NOTE: inline does _not_ mean the function will be inlined.  It _might_ be inlined, that's still up to the compiler.  However, at a language / semantics level, inline means that a function can be defined in more than one module without a link-time error. (definitions must still match though).

Comment: "You should note this does not force the compiler to make the function inline"

Comment: @FireLancer It is my understanding that it's good to inline a function when it is called often (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932311/when-to-use-inline-function-and-when-not-to-use-it).  However, you mention that if a function is used a 100 times you will have a 100 copies which causes a code bloat.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: The first part of this answer is *not* what it means for a function to be inline. It's what it means for a function call to be inlined. Only the last paragraph is what it means for a function to be inline. "Being inline" is a property of the function, but "getting inlined" is not, since where there are multiple calls to the same function some of them might get inlined and others not.

Answer (score 48):

It means one thing and one thing only: that the compiler will elide multiple definitions of the function.

A function normally cannot be defined multiple times (i.e. if you place a non-inline function definition into a header and then #include it into multiple compilation units you will receive a linker error).  Marking the function definition as "inline" suppresses this error (the linker ensures that the Right Thing happens).

IT DOES NOT MEAN ANYTHING MORE!

Most significantly, it does NOT mean that the compiler will embed the compiled function into each call site.  Whether that occurs is entirely up to the whims of the compiler, and typically the inline modifier does little or nothing to change the compiler's mind.  The compiler can--and does--inline functions that *aren't* marked inline, and it can make function calls to functions that *are* marked inline.

Eliding multiple definitions is the thing to remember.

Comment: The compilers only  inline non marked as inline functions ONLY if you request  it to do so. Inline  keyword does affect that. I know, I have worked a lot in GCC code that does that to produce  an specialization of the compiler back at university.

Comment: I have worked on GCC as well. In this poster is basically correct. This post should be at the top of the list.

Comment: Its correct only on the effcts nto the casuse. Inline do not generate any extra info that the linker may use. Compiel 2 object files and check. It allow multiple definitions exaclty because the symbols are not exported! Not because that is its goal!

Answer (score 23):

As well as the other (perfectly correct) answers about the performance implications of `inline`, in C++ you should also note this allows you to safely put a function in a header:

```
// my_thing.h
inline int do_my_thing(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

// use_my_thing.cpp
#include "my_thing.h"
...
    set_do_thing(&do_my_thing);

// use_my_thing_again.cpp
...
    set_other_do_thing(&do_my_thing);
```

This is because the compiler only includes the actual body of the function in the first object file that needs a regular callable function to be compiled (normally because it's address was taken, as I showed above).

Without the `inline` keyword, most compilers would give an error about multiple definition, eg for MSVC:

```
use_my_thing_again.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl do_my_thing(int,int)" (?do_my_thing@@YAHHH@Z) already defined in use_my_thing.obj
<...>\Scratch.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Comment: Correct answer here, unfortunately only the 3rd one at the time of this comment.

Answer (score 3):

@OldMan

> The compilers only inline non marked as inline functions ONLY if you request it to do so.

Only if by "request" you mean "turn on optimizations".

> Its correct only on the effcts nto the casuse.

It's correct in both.

> Inline do not generate any extra info that the linker may use. Compiel 2 object files and check. It allow multiple definitions exaclty because the symbols are not exported! Not because that is its goal!

What do you mean, "the symbols are not exported"?  inline functions are not static. Their names are visible; they have external linkage. To quote from the C++ Standard:

> void h();
> inline void h(); // external linkage
>
> inline void l();
> void l(); // external linkage

The multiple definitions thing is very much the goal. It's mandatory:

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is used and shall have exactly the
> same definition in every case (3.2). [Note: a call to the inline function may be encountered before its definition
> appears in the translation unit. ] If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one translation
> unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required. An
> inline function with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units.

Answer (score 2):

The function body is literally inserted inside the caller function. Thus, if you have multiple calls to this function, you get multiple copies of the code. The benefit is you get faster execution.

Usually very short function are inlined, when the copy of the function body would be not much bigger than the usual prologue/epilogue code generated for the normal function call.

You can read more at MSDN article about inline - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Inline functions alter the performance profile of your application by possibly generating instructions that are placed in the code segment of your application.  Whether a function is inlined is at the discretion of your compiler.  In my experience, most modern compilers are good at determining when to comply with a user's request to inline.

In many cases, inlining a function will improve its performance.  There is an inherent overhead to function calls.  There are reasons, however, why inlining a function could be negative:

- Increasing the size of the binary executable by duplicating code could lead to disk thrashing, slowing your application down.
- Inlining code could contribute to cache misses, or possibly contribute to cache hits depending on your architecture.

The C++ FAQ does a good job of explaining the intricacies of the keyword:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.3

Answer (score 0):

Informally, it means that compilers are allowed to graft the contents of the function onto the call site, so that there is no function call. If your function has big control statements (e.g., `if`, `switch`, etc.), and the conditions can be evaluated at compile time at the call site (e.g., constant values used at call site), then your code ends up much smaller (the unused branches are dropped off).

More formally, inline functions have different linkage too. I'll let C++ experts talk about that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function imposes a certain performance penalty for the CPU over just having a linear stream of instructions. The CPU's registers have to be written to another location, etc. Obviously the benefits of having functions usually outweigh the performance penalty. But, where performance will be an issue, for example the fabled 'inner loop' function or some other bottleneck, the compiler can insert the machine code for the function into the main stream of execution instead of going through the CPU's tax for calling a function.

Comment: You're absolutely right, folding inner loops and getting rid of far jumps causes decreasing possible lost CPU cycles due to cache misses hence increasing performance from one side, but it increases the cache footprint from the other side.
That's why it important to balancing these trade offs.

Answer (score 0):

A function that you flag as inline  is  allowed to be inlined by the compiler. There is no guarantee that compielr will do it. The compiler itself uses complex semantics to device when to do it or not.

When the compiler decides that a function should be inlined, the  call to the function, in the caller code is replaced by the code of the calee. This means you save up  stack  operations, the call itself and improve locality of code cache. Sometimes that may lead to huge performance gains. Specially  in  1 line data access functions, like the accessors used in Object Oriented code.

The cost is that usually that will result in larger code, what might hurt performance. This is why setting a function to inline  is only a "green flag" to the compiler, that it does not need to follow. The compiler will try to  do what is best.

As a rule of thumb for beginners that don't want to deal with  linkage peculiarities. inline function  are to be called by other function in same compilation units.  If you want to implement an inline function that can  be used on multiple compilation units,  make it an header file declared and implemented inline function.

Why?

Example: at header file inlinetest.h

```
int foo();
inline int bar();
```

At the compilation unit inlinetest.cpp

```
 int foo(){ int r = bar(); return r; }


 inline int bar(){ return 5;};
```

Then at the main.cpp

```
 #include "inlinetest.h"
 int main()
 {
  foo();
 //bar();
  }
```

Compile one object file at a time. If you uncomment that "bar" call you will have an error. Because the inline function is only implemented on the inlinetest.o object file and is not exported. At same time the foo function, very likely has embedded on it the code of the bar function (since bar is single line no I/O  operation then its very likely to be inlined)

But if at the header file you had declared the inline function and implemented it inline then you would be able to use it at  any compilation unit that includes that header.
("code sample");

Remove the inline keyword and compiler will NOT cause the error even with bar call at main And no inline will happen unless you ask the compiler to inline all functions. That is not standard behavior on most compilers.