# Global function definition in header file - how to avoid duplicated symbol linkage error

Tags: c++

I have the following code in a header only file.

```
#pragma once

class error_code {
public:
    unsigned __int64 hi;
    unsigned __int64 lo;    
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const error_code& e) {
    return o << "[" << e.hi << "," << e.lo << "]";
}
```

I get linkage error, when there are 2 cpp in the project include this header file.

> error LNK2005: "class error_code
>   __cdecl operator|(class error_code const &,class ViTrox::error_code const
>   &)" (??U@@YA?AVerror_code@0@ABV10@0@Z)
>   already defined in xxx.obj

I know I can resolve this problem, if I move the definition of `operator<<` to a cpp file, or to a DLL file.

However, I just would like to have them in a **SINGLE** header file. Is there any technique to achieve so? Or must I separate the definition to another file?

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code snippet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `inline` keyword.

```
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const error_code& e) {
    return o << "[" << e.hi << "," << e.lo << "]";
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know where in the spec it says that this works?  I've been using this as a hack for a while, but I've never seen conclusive proof that it works correctly.

Comment: Not chapter and verse, but IIRC if you don't have `inline` it violates ODR (and if you do have inline but two or more different bodies it also violates ODR).

Comment: The compiler must see inline and template function bodies. Otherwise it can't inline them or instantiate them at the time of compiling separate translation units.

Comment: `inline` is just a hint to the compiler, it may not inline sometimes.

Comment: @Nawaz, yes for the purposes of optimization. But in this case we're leveraging it to specify linkage.

Comment: @Nawaz: No! inline is not just a hint to the compiler. This is a correct and appropriateuse of inline.

Comment: @templatetypedef: You shouldn't consider this entirely appropriate use of inline to be a hack. It is guaranteed to work it's what inline is for, see the section on the one definition rule, reference to follow...

Comment: @Charles Bailey- Just looked it up - 3.2.3.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention!  I never knew that this was guaranteed to work.

Comment: @templatetypedef: thanks, I didn't have a standard to hand. There's lots of previous discussion on inline here as well as other questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932311/when-to-use-inline-funtion-and-when-not-to-use-it/1932580#1932580

Comment: @Logan Capaldo: inline doesn't affect a function's linkage. inline functions still have external linkage by default.

Comment: Can I pretend I used finger quotes when typing that comment?

Comment: @Logan Capaldo: Sure, why not. :)

Answer (score 7):

Either make the function `inline`:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const error_code& e) {
    return o << "[" << e.hi << "," << e.lo << "]";
}
```

or make it a template function:

```
template<class Ch, class Tr>
std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr>& operator<< (std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr>& o,
                                       const error_code& e) {
    return o << "[" << e.hi << "," << e.lo << "]";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the  function `static`. It specifies internal linkage, so the linker won't care if the function is already defined in other translation units.

Or, as already mentioned, you can make it `inline`. It still has external linkage, but the standard allows external inline functions to have a definition in multiple translation units.

Answer (score 0):

Define this function in .cpp file (not in .h file)

```
//yoursource.cpp
#include "yourheader.h"

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const error_code& e) {
    return o << "[" << e.hi << "," << e.lo << "]";
}
```