# Defining c++ global functions only in header files with zero-parameter templates?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, global

This is a follow up question to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600190/) and [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4600209/683218).

I sometimes want to define a function in a header-only manner in a `.h` file, *e.g.*:

```
int id(int i) { return i; }
```

I know this can be done using `inline` functions. As I read from the comments

> inline is just a hint to the compiler, it may not inline sometimes

Based on the linked answer above, it seems also possible just to

> make it a template function

by *e.g.* using a dummy type variable in a header `test.h` as follows:

```
template <typename T = void>
int id(int i) { return i; }
```

and then use it in a source file below with `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp test2.cpp`

```
#include "test.h"
int main() { return id(1); }
```

(`test2.cpp` is a copy of `test.cpp` with the `main()` function renamed to something else)

My questions are:

1. *Is the above technique with templates safe to use with respect to ODR and compilation? (In other words, is there any case in which the above technique will fail?)*
2. *If so, is it possible to rewrite the template and drop the dummy template variable `T` (`typename T = void`) in order to make it shorter (i.e., zero-parametered) and less noisy?*

Comment: Since the `template` is dis-information to maintainers, it's not safe to use. Use the language feature that does what you want, namely `inline`.

Answer (score 3):

> > inline is just a hint to the compiler, it may not inline sometimes

Though that's correct how *inlined*<sup>1</sup> code is handled by the linker, the `inline` keyword is necessary for non templated free function definitions appearing in header files to prevent multiple definition errors at the linking phase.

**In other words:**
If a matching *inlined*<sup>1</sup> definition of a function is seen at the linking phase `inline` allows to identify its source and decide to replace it with the first definition seen by the linker (actually *inlined*<sup>1</sup> or not).

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>***Inlined*** in that context means that some simple statement that would e.g. just require some simple CPU register operations, can be replaced with these, instead of emitting a complete function call frame.</sub>