# Should I write my own merge function or use std::merge if I'm calling it thousands of time. Are there any performance improvements for one over other?

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, inline

So, I am using std::merge and std::inplace_merge several thousand times in my code. I have read about inline keyword which is used for optimizations. So, writing my own merge functions and make it inline is gonna be useful? Or it is already optimized by the compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1932371/4045598

Comment: Can you write a better merge function for your use-case than what is provided by your standard library? If yes, go for it. If not, well, no point.

Comment: Start with the Library function. It's tried, tested and true. If the If the project requirements say you need more speed, then profile and see if the merge is the right place for an improvement. If the profiling says you need something better (and as Mat says can write something better), then do the extra work.