# How to auto increment the destination pointer with memcpy()?

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

Basically I need to do multiple `memcpy()` and I don't want to increment the destination pointer `dst++;` after every `memcpy()` call.. just wondering how to save some coding time.

```
memcpy(dest, src1, 1); // uint8_t
dest += 1;
memcpy(dest, src2, 2); // uint16_t
dest += 2;
memcpy(dest, src3, 1024); // uint8_t*
dest += 1024;
...
```

How to do multiple `memcpy()` that increment the destination pointer for you?

Comment: For example dest += 2;  or memcpy(dest + 1, src2, 2); ?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you, True, incrementation in one line is a solution.

Comment: `static inline void *CopyAndUpdate(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n) { return (char *) memcpy(s1, s2, n) + n; }`, then `dest = CopyAndUpdate(dest, src1, 1); dest = CopyAndUpdate(dest, src1, 2);`. Or `static inline void CopyAndUpdate(char * restrict * s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n) { memcpy(*s1, s2, n); *s1 += n; }`, then `CopyAndUpdate(&dest, src, 1); CopyAndUpdate(&dest, src, 2);`, presuming the type of `dest` is `char *`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. True, but this is just an example, my real data up to 1024 * 4 bytes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you Eric, your answer is complete. your function is exactly what I need.

Comment: @EricPostpischil inlining will happen anyway.

Comment: @ShellX3 char size versison will not work for more than one byte size objects. Something more generic is needed.

Comment: @0__: In OP's example, `sizeof *dest` must be `1`, because otherwise it would not make sense that OP is passing `1` as the third parameter to `memcpy`. But you are right that the question is unclear in this respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function:

```
void memcpy_auto_inc( char **pp_dest, const void *src, size_t count )
{
    memcpy( *pp_dest, src, count );
    *pp_dest += count;
}
```

Now, assuming that `dest` is of type `char*`, instead of writing

```
memcpy( dest, src1, 1 );
dest += 1;
memcpy( dest, src2, 2 );
dest += 2;
memcpy( dest, src3, 1024 );
dest += 1024;
```

you can write:

```
memcpy_auto_inc( &dest, src1, 1 );
memcpy_auto_inc( &dest, src2, 2 );
memcpy_auto_inc( &dest, src3, 1024 );
```

However, I doubt that this is worth the effort, as it makes the code less clear and doesn't save you much typing, even if you select a much shorter name for the function than `memcpy_auto_inc`.

EDIT:

On request of OP, I will provide additional information regarding `restrict` and `inline` optimizations:

The function `memcpy_auto_inc` can be further optimized by changing the function prototype to use the [`restrict`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) type qualifier:

```
void memcpy_auto_inc( char *restrict *restrict pp_dest, const void *restrict src, size_t count )
```

It would also be possible to add the [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline) function specifier. However, in my opinion, this is not necessary, as it is unlikely that this will result in increased run-time performance. You can generally rely on the compiler's optimizer to make the decision on whether it is appropriate to inline a function.

This topic is further discussed in this question:

[When to use inline function and when not to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1932311/12149471)

However, that question is 12 years old and compiler's optimizers have improved significantly since then, so there is now even less reason to use the `inline` keyword.

Comment: Side effects are one of the C devils. When not absolutely needed should be avoided at any price. `memcpy(dest, src2, 2);
dest+=2;` is much better than `memcpy_auto_inc( &dest, src2, 2);` because it is obvious that the pointer is **modified** here

Comment: @0__: I agree. But OP asked for something other than `memcpy(dest, src2, 2); dest+=2;` that saves coding time.

Comment: But IMO it is the worst option. Why realloc returns value instead of taking the double pointer. To avoid SE

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, Can we use `restrict` and `inline` in your `memcpy_auto_inc()` for more optimization?

Comment: @ShellX3: I have edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Excellent explanation, Thank you Wenzel.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own function.

for example generic for any size elements:

```
void *generic(void *dest, const void *src, const size_t elemsize, size_t nelems)
{
    char *cptr = dest;

    memcpy(dest, src, elemsize * nelems);
    cptr += nelems * elemsize;
    return cptr;
}
```

or as in your example (char size elements)

```
void *charSizeOnly(void *dest, const void *src, size_t nelems)
{
    char *cptr = dest;

    memcpy(dest, src, nelems);
    cptr += nelems;
    return cptr;
}
```

example usage:

```
    mytype *dest;
    mytype *src;
    /* ... some code*/
    /*it will copy and update the dest by 30 elements of type `mytype`*/
    dest = generic(dest, src, sizeof(*dest), 30);
```