# Shortening C++ template function name

Tags: c++, c++11

I know, that to shorten class names I can do the following:

```
using Time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;
using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
```

But how to properly reduce length of the next line?

```
/*using Ms = */ std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
```

The target piece of code:

```
Time start = Clock::now();
// something
Time end = Clock::now();
std::cout << Ms(end - start).count() << std::endl;
```

Comment: You can not create aliases of functions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9864125/1896169

Comment: @Justin I want to use this pice of code in headers, so I prefer not to write such things. And I think duration_cast is still ugly and long.

Comment: You can make a helper function:  `inline auto Ms(decltype(Time{} - Time{}) duration) { return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration); }`

Comment: @Eljay That's an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple options. You could use a [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace):

```
void foo() {
    // These can be scoped to the function so they don't bleed into your API
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;

    Time start = Clock::now();
    // something
    Time end = Clock::now();
    std::cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count() << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you could write your own function:

```
template <typename Duration>
auto as_ms(Duration const& duration) {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration);
}

void foo() {
    Time start = Clock::now();
    // something
    Time end = Clock::now();
    std::cout << as_ms(end - start).count() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: See, now your answer is an answer!  My comment was just a notion.  ;-)

Comment: @Eljay Yes, but there's no reason why you couldn't have posted that as an answer. :)

Comment: So, why not inline auto as Eljay stated?

Comment: You could also have a single `using`-declaration for the entire `std::chrono` namespace. I understand why you might not want a `using`-declaration for a whole namespace in a larger scope, but for a function of this size the danger seems minimal.

Comment: @BenS. I wouldn't recommend `using namespace std::chrono;` It's analogy in other languages is a `*` import (e.g. `import java.util.*;`) It's not a good idea in most cases, as you could easily end up with a name collision. If the number of `using` declarations you need is small (in this case it's only 2), it's not much more typing anyway. OTOH, I do use namespace aliases all the time (`namespace chr = std::chrono;`)

Comment: @BhavinChirag This is equivalent. You can add the `inline` keyword. Since the function I wrote is a template function, it's implicitly `inline` (it makes no difference to add it). If you want to make the function not a template, you'd have to add the `inline` keyword (assuming you put the definition in a header file). Eljay's function wasn't a template; it used a concrete type as an argument. I tend to prefer templates for situations like this, where there are multiple types that work

Comment: @Justin Maybe I am wrong but I thought that in some cases compiler will not inline it.

Comment: @BhavinChirag The `inline` keyword has an unfortunate name. It isn't a hint to the compiler to inline the function. All it means is that you can put the function definition in a header file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/157929/1896169). However, the compiler will see that all this function does is call another function, so - in practice - this function *will* be inlined by the compiler

Answer (score 4):

As of c++17, lambdas are constexpr by default, which makes them excellent aliases for template functions without all the unpleasant template syntax:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void test()
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using Time = Clock::time_point;

    auto Ms = [](auto&& duration)
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count();
    };

    auto start = Clock::now();
    // something
    auto end = Clock::now();
    std::cout << Ms(end - start) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you refer to as *shortening class names* is actually type aliasing. [Type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) are used for types. `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>` is not a type. It is a function. You can not make aliases for functions.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear for me. I want to know is there a beautiful solution, because I always can use #define with that string to solve the problem.

Comment: There are aliases for function pointers and you can also wrap the function into another function. Whether you should is another subject.

Comment: @BhavinChirag I strongly recommend not using a `#define`. If you do want to use it, be certain that you `#undef` it.

Comment: @Justin Indeed. Definitely avoid `#define` and (too much) macro programming.

Answer (score -1):

The preprocessor is there for you to take advantage of, if you want to, you can just use macros.

```
#define TIME std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>
#define CLOCK std::chrono::system_clock;
#define TIME_AS_MS std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
```